# Why my implementation of Conway's Game of Life in java does not work?

Tags: java, algorithm, conways-game-of-life

<s>I’m trying to develop a program demonstrating Conway’s Game of Life. The algorithm I’ve written looks simple and meaningful to me, though the JRE seemingly is not agree with me. Each cell object have two states, indicating whether it’s alive and it’s active. Simply, activation of a cell occurs only when the algorithm iterates over the all members of the Cell two dimensional array. This is the most important aspect of the program because program needs to know what was the previous state of all of the cells. And finally, the birth of a new cell occurs when *neighbor checking algorithm* finds out a cell(alive or not) is surrounded with 3 cells.</s>

I calculate the number of neighbors of an individual cell by looking whether the surrounding cell is active or not. So when a new cell was born, it doesn't consider. It works as expected.

What is the problem with my algorithm I fail to see?

**UPDATE**

I have found out that neighbor checking algorithm produce erroneous data inside my brand new process() method. Also, I changed the basic algorithm behind the game. Instead of having a single array which holds two states at the mean time, I started using two separate 2D boolean array. It made things a lot easier. Yet, program continues to come up with interesting and unwelcome data.

```
private void process(){
    boolean[][] temp = new boolean[BOARD_LENGTH][BOARD_LENGTH];

    for(int i=0; i<cells.length; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<cells[i].length; j++){
            if(i == 5 && j == 5)
                System.out.println(getNeighborNumbers(i,j));//THIS IS WHERE I NOTICED THE PROBLEM. OUTSIDE THİS process() method, getNeighborNumbers() method works flawlessly, though when it comes here, things get interesting. 
            if(getNeighborNumbers(i,j) < 2 || getNeighborNumbers(i,j) > 3 )
                temp[i][j] = false;
            else if(cells[i][j] = true && getNeighborNumbers(i,j) == 2)
                temp[i][j] = true;
            else if(getNeighborNumbers(i,j) == 3)
                temp[i][j] = true;
        }


    for(int i=0; i<cells.length; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<cells.length; j++)
            cells[i][j] = temp[i][j];

    /*
    System.out.println("5,4 " + getNeighborNumbers(5,4) +" "+ cells[5][4]);
    System.out.println("5,5 " + getNeighborNumbers(5,5) +" "+ cells[5][5]);
    System.out.println("5,6 " + getNeighborNumbers(5,6) +" "+ cells[5][6]);
    System.out.println("6,5 " + getNeighborNumbers(6,5) +" "+ cells[6][5]);
    System.out.println("6,6 " + getNeighborNumbers(6,6) +" "+ cells[6][6]);
    */

}


private int getNeighborNumbers(int i, int j){
    int neighbors = 0;

    if(i>0 && j>0 && cells[i-1][j-1] == true)
        neighbors++;
    if(i>0 && cells[i-1][j] == true)
        neighbors++;
    if(i>0 && j+1< BOARD_LENGTH && cells[i-1][j+1] == true)
        neighbors++;
    if(j>0 && cells[i][j-1] == true)
        neighbors++;
    if(j+1<BOARD_LENGTH && cells[i][j+1] == true)
        neighbors++;
    if(i+1<BOARD_LENGTH && j>0 && cells[i+1][j-1] == true)
        neighbors++;
    if(i+1 <BOARD_LENGTH && cells[i+1][j] == true)
        neighbors++;
    if(i+1<BOARD_LENGTH && j+1<BOARD_LENGTH && cells[i+1][j+1] == true)
        neighbors++;

    return neighbors;
}
```

What might be the problem causing getNeighborNumbers to produce incorrect data? I believe my algorithm is simple as it can be.

**MOST RECENT UPDATE**
Well, apparently instead of writing ==, I've written =. I could have never thought this kind of simple erroneous statement cost me hours.

Comment: lots of code; absolutely no mention of what it is or is not doing correctly?

Comment: the edit removes about 90% of the code dump that was unrelated, don't encourage useless fix my code dumps like this

Comment: "Simply, activation of a cell occurs only when the algorithm iterates over the all members of the Cell two dimensional array." -- Activation occurs based on the previous states only. Maarten's right when your code changes the state then the next bit uses that changed state rather than the previous state of a copy. You make a copy, then do that to create the new activation state of the board. Rather than simply iterate over the board in a scan line corrupting the state each time.

Answer (score 2):

You're changing the cells as you go, so you don't use the state of the cells *of the previous iteration*.

In other words, you need to store the state of the previous "board" and use it to create a new board.

Comment: I do use the state of the previous iteration in a way. Neighbor counting algorithm only considers **active cells** and a cell only becomes an active one after algorithms complete their work.

Comment: Actually, @BurakGüneş, from what I can see that is not true. You call `getNeighbourNumbers`, which you don't show us, then change the state of the cell, then call that anonymous method again, then change the state, ... Unless `getNeighbourNumbers` has kept a defensive copy of the board, not shown in this post, that spells trouble. You also don't show `refreshStates`, so I don't really think anyone can help.

Comment: @BurakGüneş, yeah, given your now edit Maarten's answer is clearly correct. Conways game of life must be done with a copy of the board last time and the new copy of the board. Much like an convolution operation. You can only do what you're doing there by shifting up and to the right in a weird way. But clearly you're corrupting the data with a scan line information.